# Does systemd-timesyncd need to listen to random UDP ports to work properly?

Tags: debian, systemd, debian-jessie, time-synchronization, debian-stretch

On Debian Jessie servers I see `systemd-timesyncd` listening on random UDP ports. Which is not the case on Debian Stretch hosts. By random I mean the port it listens to varies from server to server. Does it need to listen to a UDP port to work properly? I want to block ports that are not needed. Does this mean I've got to leave all UDP ports open?

Comment: Exactly what are you seeing?

Comment: @MichaelHampton probably something like `udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51826           0.0.0.0:*  17697/systemd-timesyncd` where the port is a random ephemeral port.

Comment: @MichaelHampton For example, on one server `ss -unlp` gives `UNCONN   0   0   *:36956   *:*   users:(("systemd-timesyn",pid=525,fd=12))`.

Comment: I encountered the same thing on Ubuntu 20. I do not have a stateful firewall so the answer below is not applicable for my case. My question for this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1064319/systemd-timesyncd-requires-incoming-ephemeral-ports-opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The systemd-timesyncd mostly is a ntp/sntp client.  IE it will make outbound requests, and get replies.  If you are running a **statefull** firewall then you would need to permit outgoing UDP traffic, and ESTABLISHED/RELATED incoming traffic.  You shouldn't need to permit incoming traffic to the port the timesyncd is listening on.